# How do I calculate a monthly payment from the *beginning* of the month?

Tags: finance

I'm needing to calculate monthly payments -- but from the **beginning** of the month, as opposed to the end which appears to be standard. This is the standard monthly payment formula:

$$M = P\frac{i(1+i)^n}{(1+i)^n-1}$$

(M=monthly payment, P=principal, i=interest rate, n=number of payments)

What changes need to be made so it's calculating from the beginning of the month? What I'm trying to do is the equivalent of the Excel formula =PMT(A1,A2,A3,,**1**) but I don't need to know the *result* of the calculation so much as I need to know how to *do* it and I can't seem to Google anything up.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use $n-1$ instead of $n$

Comment: I can't believe it's that simple. Thank you!

Comment: I don´t think that is that simple.